# number system converter python

Tags: python, numbers

Hi I want to make my own number converter that converts an input of binary, octal or hexadecimal to the corresponding decimal value.

I have to use 2 separate functions, the first to convert the alphabetical digits to numerical values then the second to convert the result of that by using the input base to be converted to a decimal value...

```
   def hexConvert (x):
    return int(x, base)

x = str(input("input value to convert to decimal: "))
base = int(input("Base of value to be converted to decimal: "))
print(x, " in base ", base, " = ", hexConvert(x), " in decimal")
```

I know this works very well and is robust. I want to learn how to use more python functions by doing it manually.

This is what I currently have:

```
    number = (input("Enter value to be converted to decimal: "))
base = int(input("Enter the base of the value: "))

for index in number:
    print(index)
def hexConvert(number, base):
    for number > 0:
        if number == 1:
            return 1
        if number == 2:
            return 2
        if number == 3:
            return 3
        if number == 4:
            return 4
        if number == 5:
            return 5
        if number == 6:
            return 6
        if number == "7":
            return 7
        if number == "8":
            return 8
        if number == "9":
            return 9
        if number == "A":
            return 10
        if number == "B":
            return 11
        if number == "C":
            return 12
        if number == "D":
            return 13
        if number == "E":
            return  14
        elif number == "F":
            return 15
        else:
            print(number)


nString = ""
def deciConvert(number, base):
    number = int(number)
    while number > 0:
        bString = number%base
        nString = nString + str(bString)
        number = number // base

print(deciConvert(number, base))
```

I've lost myself at this point, I think I haven't started any calculations yet, I would really appreciate any 2nd opinions.
Thank you!

Comment: `for number > 0:` is invalid syntax, and your `if` statements aren't consistent about whether they compare `number` to a string or an int.

Comment: yep, sometimes you are comparing to strings and sometimes to numbers.

Comment: Use a dictionary instead of that awfully long `if`: `chr2num = {str(i) if i < 10 else chr(ord('A') + i - 10) : i for i in range(16)}`. Then simply do this: `chr2num[number]` to get the "actual" number (in base 10).

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend generic `encode` and `dec_to_base` functions

```
ALPHABET = \
  "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

def encode (n):
  try:
    return ALPHABET [n]
  except IndexError:
    raise Exception ("cannot encode: %s" % n)

def dec_to_base (dec = 0, base = 16):
  if dec < base:
    return encode (dec)
  else:
    return dec_to_base (dec // base, base) + encode (dec % base)

print (dec_to_base (9))
# 9

print (dec_to_base (10))
# a

print (dec_to_base (255))
# ff

print (dec_to_base (256))
# 100
```

Of course it works with other bases

```
print (dec_to_base (255, base = 2))
# 11111111

print (dec_to_base (256, base = 2))
# 100000000
```

Reversing an encoding is done by providing the isomorphisms `decode` and `base_to_dec`

```
def decode (s):
  try:
    return ALPHABET.index(s)
  except ValueError:
    raise Exception ("cannot decode: %s" % s)

def base_to_dec (s, base = 16, pow = 0):
  if s is "":
    return 0
  else:
    return decode (s[-1]) * (base ** pow) + base_to_dec (s[0:-1], base, pow + 1)

print (base_to_dec ('ff'))
# 255

print (base_to_dec ('100'))
# 256
```

And using a different base

```
print (dec_to_base ('11111111', base = 2))
# 255

print (dec_to_base ('100000000', base = 2))
# 256
```

Comment: `encode`-ing using lists (especially if saved as a constant) is probably even faster than the dictionary idea that I suggested in the comments. +1

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a function to translate from any base to any base. It might be some slow, but it works.

```
import math
def convert(number, number_base, output_base):
    number = str(number)
    output = ''
    decimal_input = 0
    index = len(number)-1
    for char in number:
        decimal_input += number_base.index(char)*(len(number_base)**index)
        index -= 1  
    index = math.ceil(math.sqrt(decimal_input / len(output_base)))
    while index >= 0:
        if not (len(output) == 0 and decimal_input // len(output_base)**index == 0):
            output += output_base[decimal_input // len(output_base)**index]
        decimal_input %= len(output_base)**index
        index -= 1
    return output
```

To use that, just create two strings like this:

```
decimal = '0123456789'
hex = '0123456789ABCDEF'
hex_100 = convert('100', decimal, hex)
print(hex_100)  #64
```

You can use this for any numeric base, also like: `weird = '.g'`.
In this case, `weird` would be a binary system where "." is 0 and "g" is 1. Attention: not working with float or negative numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
def hextodec(str_in, base):
    dec = int(str_in, base)
    return dec

if __name__ == "__main__":
    hex = input()
    base = int(input()) 
    hextodec(hex, base)
```